# Inserting a cross-reference with Aspose Words

Tags: ms-word, aspose, cross-reference

Does anybody know if it is possible to insert a cross reference (I want to reference a bookmark, but I could make anything else work as well), using Aspose Words, in C#?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a footnote or endnote, you can use the following code.

```
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.Write("Some text is added.");
Footnote endNote = new Footnote(doc, FootnoteType.Endnote);
builder.CurrentParagraph.AppendChild(endNote);
endNote.Paragraphs.Add(new Paragraph(doc));
endNote.FirstParagraph.Runs.Add(new Run(doc, "Endnote text."));
doc.Save(MyDir + @"FootNote.docx");
```

If you want to insert a bookmark, you can use the following code.

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.StartBookmark("MyBookmark");
builder.Writeln("Text inside a bookmark.");
builder.EndBookmark("MyBookmark")
```

If you want to update a bookmark, you can use the following code.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "Bookmark.doc");

// Use the indexer of the Bookmarks collection to obtain the desired bookmark.
Bookmark bookmark = doc.Range.Bookmarks["MyBookmark"];

// Get the name and text of the bookmark.
string name = bookmark.Name;
string text = bookmark.Text;

// Set the name and text of the bookmark.
bookmark.Name = "RenamedBookmark";
bookmark.Text = "This is a new bookmarked text.";
```

I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thank you @muhammad-ijaz

I do not have a problem with adding a bookmark.  
What I want to do, is to insert text that will show what page that bookmark is on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the page number of a bookmark.

```
Document doc = new Document("Bookmark.docx");
Aspose.Words.Layout.LayoutCollector layoutCollector = new Aspose.Words.Layout.LayoutCollector(doc);

// Use the indexer of the Bookmarks collection to obtain the desired bookmark.
Bookmark bookmark = doc.Range.Bookmarks["MyBookmark"];

// Get the name and text of the bookmark.
string name = bookmark.Name;
string text = bookmark.Text;
int pageNumber = layoutCollector.GetStartPageIndex(bookmark.BookmarkStart);

Console.Write("Bookmark name is {0}, it is placed on page number {1} and following is the text inside it: {2}", name, pageNumber, text);
```

Comment: Thank you. I can try this, however I need to put the page numbers back into the word document, and there is a potential that the page numbers of the bookmarks will change.  That is why I wanted a reference. Doing it in word is very easy, so it is frustrating that I can't figure out how to do it with Aspose.  Maybe referencing the word API directly.

Comment: You can share your expected output document with reference to this thread in Aspose.Words forum. This will help us share the correct code according to your requirement.